# Openshift deployment reserve file timestamp

Tags: openshift

Every times I deploy my repo to Openshift via Git, the timestamps of all the files change to current. This can be seen at `~/app-deployments/current/repo`. I display last modification time to my pages, so I do not want all of them to change. Is it possible to make Openshift retain timestamps for unchanged files?

Comment: Openshift redeploys the whole application when you push the git. you can use `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` to store persistent files or use Linux command `touch` to change the modification time after deployment.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I may do it with [action hooks](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/action-hooks.html) and some [environment variables](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/environment-variables.html), but it is not a trivia thing.